# How can I run a Flask application

Tags: python-3.x, flask

The Flask official website says that we can run a Flask application by

```
$ export FLASK_APP=hello.py
$ flask run
```

1. The second command doesn't work for me.

   ```
   $ flask run    
   Command 'flask' not found, but can be installed with:  
   sudo apt install python3-flask
   ```

   Instead this works

   ```
   python3 -m flask run
   ```

   How can I make the second command works? If I run `sudo apt install python3-flask`, will I get two installations of flask?
2. Can the two commands be combined into one command without using environment variable?

Answer (score 4):

Bear with me as I will try to explain the different pieces and how they all interconnect. `export FLASK_APP=hello.py` is *setting an operating system environment variable* called `FLASK_APP` and is simply *pointing to the entry file to start your flask application*. This is no different than setting any other environment variable on your operating system. Now the flask team has provided everyone with a command called `flask run` which can be used to *start up your flask application* and this command will use the value set within your `FLASK_APP` environment variable when it attempts to start your flask server. So the reason why your `python3 -m flask run` command works is because you're telling your operating system's install of python to run the `flask run` command as a script, which is how this command is intended to be invoked.

For reference:

```
-m mod : run library module as a script (terminates option list)
```

Additionally, python attempts to resolve modules from it's `sys.path` environment variable and it looks in the following order of directories to resolve the requested module:

1. The **current directory** where the script has been invoked. This is why you can *always import modules contained in the same directory as one another*.
2. The value of your `PYTHONPATH` environment variable
3. The standard library directory on your path
4. Lastly, the site packages directory, i.e. **your third party packages** like `flask`

Now the reason your `flask run` command didn't initially work is because **python couldn't find flask within any of the four locations listed above**. However, once you gave the `-m` python knew to look in your `site-packages` directory for `flask` and was able to find said module.

For reference you can see where python is looking to resolve modules by printing out the `sys.path` variable to the console:

```
import sys
print(sys.path)
```

Ok so that answers the first part of your first question, now as for the second part of your first question:

*"If I run `sudo apt install python3-flask`, will I get two installations of flask?"*

Yes, this would *install flask globally on your system* and I would highly advise against this as you can mess up your system pretty badly if you're not careful. So how do I avoid messing with my system level python configurations?

[Virtualenv](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/latest/) to the rescue, Virtual environments allow you to have a sandboxed area to play around with libraries. With the worst case scenario being you blow them away and start fresh if you screwed something up, without affecting your Operating System's install of python. *You should have a one to one relationship between each python project and virtual environment*. If you use `virtualenv` I highly suggest looking into [Virtualenvwrapper](https://virtualenvwrapper.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) which wraps `virtualenv` with easier to remember commands. Although I think all the cool kids are using [pipenv](https://pipenv.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) now so you may want to look into that as well, I will leave that decision up to you. What's nice is once you've activated your virtual environment and are developing you can just use `flask run` since your virtual environment will be on your python path.

As for your second question: *"Can the two commands be combined into one command without using environment variable?"*

No you would still need to set the `FLASK_APP` environment variable to use `flask run` since it looks for the value of that environment variable to start your flask server. Perhaps you could try something like:

```
FLASK_APP=hello.py flask run
```

on the command line and see if that helps you, but you're still setting the `FLASK_APP` environment variable. Alternatively, you could just start the entry file for your flask server directly, with a:

```
python hello.py
```

I know that was a lot, but hopefully that helps clarify things for you!